# Does Wordpress always create unique passwords?

Tags: database, users, password

As you know, Wordpress db has a `wp_users` table where there is a `user_pass` field.

Is it possible that two or more different users have exactly the same `user_pass` value in that field?

Comment: `user_pass` is not a unique column, so *technically* the same value could be in there twice, but whatever hashing is done seems to involve some randomness or incorporates the current time, because I added a couple of users with the same password but the password hash was different.

Comment: That's exactly what I did before posting  :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Theoretically No! But practically Yes!**

Every new framework/CMS now implements some sort of library that adds randomness to the actual password. Its a randomly generated salt in form of a random string or time, etc. That is saved along with the hash password in database.

Since theoretically, a collision can occur in any cryptographic function so User passwords may not be considered unique. But practically we know that even for a simple md5 hash algorithm we need to hash about 2^64 values to get a single collision on average.

So practically its impossible to ever see two users with same password.